# Does the word "welfare" have an abbreviation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations

I was listening to a lecture about Mercantilism where I heard a word that sounded like *Welf*.
I tried to find if this word exists but I didn't find. In the lecture I heard this:

> The amassing of gold in payment for
>   exports in excess of imports would
>   allow a nation to build the *welf*.

By the context I suppose that *welf* is an abbreviation of "welfare", but I'm not sure. Can you tell me what is the word heard? Or, if *welf* sure is an abbreviation of "welfare"?

Comment: I've never heard *welf* before, and I'm not really sure that *welfare* would make a ton of sense there.  Are you sure it wasn't *wealth*?

Comment: I think this is too localised. It's akin to the auditory equivalent of a typo, except the mistake is by the hearer, not the speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if a speaker says *welf* instead of *wealth*, that is a mistake by the speaker, not the listener.

Comment: @jwpat7: If you want to be pedantic, I suppose. But in fact *many* people articulate "th" as "f" in at least some contexts. Particularly, for example, if the following consonant is sibilant. So I would classify it as more the hearer's than the speaker's mistake if *"A toast to your good helf, Sir"* were misunderstood as introducing some strange new word into the utterance. It's harder to spot what's going on because of the transcription difference, but at the phonetic level that really is a trivial "deviation from standard pronunciation".

Comment: That could've gone either way: a hearer could _hear_ "welf" when "wealth" was said, or a speaker could _say_ "welf" when "wealth" was meant. (Lots of people misspeak or mishear from time to time.) The net result would be the same: "Huh?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you heard ***wealth***:

> - an abundance of valuable possessions or money
> - the state of being rich
> - material prosperity

(And no, I don't know of any common abbreviation for “welfare”.)

Comment: I just thought in abbreviation because the only word that came to my mind was "welfare".

Comment: @Ed: Don't forget to mark a question as answered once your question was answered! :)

Comment: @MrHen  I don't know how to do that! Could you help? I marked one of the answers as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Ed: Looks good! Once you see the little green checkmark than the answer has been accepted. You can see which questions of yours still need an accepted answer on your profile. Click your name and look for a green box around the number of answers. If the box is missing, go into the question and look for an answer to accept.