# Does the pejorative "welfie" exist?

Tags: meaning, etymology, pejorative-language

Inspired by a [possible mishearing of "wealth" as "welf"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22566/does-the-word-welfare-have-an-abbreviation) I recalled the word "welfie" to describe someone currently on welfare. The context was always extremely negative and seemed to hint at someone with "welfare babies." Searching for *welfie*, *welfy* and *welfare baby* isn't revealing much. [NGrams suggests](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=welfare%20baby,welfare%20babies&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) "welfare baby" *is* used with spikes in the late 60s and throughout the 90s. [No results](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=welfie,welfy&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for "welfie" or "welfy" were found. A [OneLook search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=welf*) for `welf*` pointed me toward "welfare mother" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=welfare%20mother)) and "welfare queen" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_queen)). The latter is most similar to what I think the term "welfie" implied:

> A welfare queen is a pejorative phrase used in the United States to describe people who are accused of collecting excessive welfare payments through fraud or manipulation.

Having done due diligence, I am kicking this to the curb. Has anyone else heard "welfie" or have another avenue I can search? I most likely heard the term spoken and most likely in an East Texas city of roughly 20,000 population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Welfie* appears in the [related terms for *Yuppie* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuppie), meaning "a poor urban professional", but there's no reference given.

However, I did come across [this list of "Essex" terms](http://www.volkszone.com/VZi/archive/index.php?t-455356.html) (Essex is a county just north-east of London). *Welfie*, meaning rich, appears down towards the bottom of the list.

Here in the UK then, it means something more like *wealthy* than *on welfare*. Substituting *th* with *f* is fairly common in some dialects in England.

I also found [this blog](http://watertreading.blogspot.com/2011/02/welfare-state-bigger-n-badder-than-ever.html) for you. This gentleman appears to be from the US, and using *welfie* as short for *welfare*, though not quite in the same way as you suggested.

Last, I found [this book review](http://www.curledup.com/lastundr.htm), which uses *welfie* in the way you describe.

(For reference, I found these by Googling terms like *skiving welfie* and *poor welfie*. Sometimes searching for related terms can narrow the search down. Also Google will automatically try to correct your spelling, in this case unhelpfully.)